# How to compare and remove objects from a Set<E> based on condition

Tags: java

I have a Set named scripts. The class E has elements like id,squence and many more . I want to compare two rows of object E in scripts and remove only if id and sequence are same . how do I do it .I have a code that removes all the rows . Can anyone correct this code to remove only the ones that has id and sequence same .

```
        LinkedList<EditorScriptRow> lList = new LinkedList<EditorScriptRow>       (_scriptRows);

     for (ListIterator<EditorScriptRow> i = lList.listIterator(); i.hasNext();) {
           EditorScriptRow row = i.next();
         int k =0;
        for (ListIterator<EditorScriptRow> j = lList.listIterator(k+1) j.hasNext();) {

           EditorScriptRow row1 = j.next();

            if ((row.getTemplateRow().getId() != null) && 
               (row.getSequence() != null) && 
                (row.getEdit().getName() != null) ) {
                if ((row.getSequence().equals(row1.getSequence())) &&
                    (row.getTemplateRow().getId().equals(row1.getTemplateRow  ().getId      ())) && 
                    (row.getEdit().getName().equals(row1.getEdit().getName()))) {
                        _scriptRows.remove(row);
                }
        }
    }
k++;
}
```

Comment: Please format your code, this one is hard to read. Consider aligning the indentation and place the curly braces consistently. Thanks

Comment: to make your life easier, and to consolidate logic, I suggest also implemented the equals() method which does your sequence, ID, and name equality checks.

Comment: You code is missing coloring, and nice indentation. That would make it easier to answer. Maybe you want to edit it? I use 8 spaces in the beginning of each line, and it's automatically colored nicely :-)

Answer (score 2):

You mentioned "Set" but your code use LinkedList. Which one is it?

Do you have access to the source code for EditorScriptRow class?

If you do, you can override the equals method.
The contract for the Set interface is that it may not contains two objects that are considered equal by the "equals" method. So you can use an implementation of Set (such as HashSet) and this way, you can just add the object to the Set and you are guaranteed to have no duplicate items.

Comment: Would need to override the hashCode method too  - "If two objects are equal according to the equals(Object)  method, then calling the hashCode method on each of the two objects must produce the same integer result" - http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode()

Answer (score 1):

I would compile a list of id+sequence and check against that. I've just scribbled this out so it may need some refinement but something like..

```
Set idSequence = new HashSet();
for ( Iterator iterator = list.iterator(); iterator.hasNext(); )
{
  EditorScriptRow row = (EditorScriptRow) iterator.next();
  if ( ( row.getTemplateRow().getId() != null )
    && ( row.getSequence() != null )
    && ( row.getEdit().getName() != null ) )
  {
    String idAndSequence = row.getTemplateRow().getId() + row.getSequence();
    if ( idSequence.contains( idAndSequence ) )
    {
      iterator.remove();
    }
    else
    {
      idSequence.add( idAndSequence );
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: List idSequence = new ArrayList() should be replaced with Set idSequence = new HashSet() for better performance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use remove() on the iterator to remove the last element returned by next().

Answer (score 0):

override equals in EditorScriptRow

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (o instanceof EditorScriptRow) {
        EditorScriptRow other = (EditorScriptRow) o;
        return this.id.equals(other.id) && this.sequence.equals(other.sequence);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Then create a Set instead of a linked list.

```
Set<EditorScriptRow> set = new HashSet<EditorScriptRow>();
```

When you add EditorScriptRow objects to the set, duplicates will be ignored because you have overriden equals in this way

You may wish to view some Java collections tutorials if this doesn't make sense http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/collections/index.html